# Prove for a coupled system of non-linear ODE the value of a variable is always positive

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

There is a system of Non-Linear ODE of 3 variables: x,y,z defined as:
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -2kx^2 -kxy$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = kx^2 -kxy$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt} = 3kxy$$
with the initial conditions $x(0)=1$, $y(0)=0$ and $z(0)=0$ and k is any positive number. Show that the value of $y$ is always greater than 0.

Note: The equation for z is not of any direct use but it gives a conservation condition in tandem with the other ODEs ie. $x+2y+z=1$

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Where does this problem come from? What have you tried so far? Have you seen a similar problem elsewhere?

Comment: It's a system of equations that model a genetic system I have devised. I have tried solving the first two equations as a coupled DE but the second order DE has no clear functional form. Thus is not helpful. I require an analytical proof that there is always some y left ie. y>0

Answer (score 2):

Note that whenever $y = 0$, $dy/dt \ge 0$ (strictly except at the point $(0,0)$ which is an equilibrium).

Comment: This doesn't give any important clue as we can just say initially y increases and the lowest it can go is 0. Which is obvious

Comment: What is obvious?  If you mean that $y$ is $0$ at the initial time, later it is positive (as shown by Robert Israel), and **it reaches again the value zero at some finite time**, that is not only not obvious, but just impossible.

Comment: The point is this.  Suppose $y(T)=0$ for some $T> 0$; take the first such $T$ if there's more than one.  Thus $y(t) > 0$ for $0 < t < T$, and $\dot{y}(T) \le 0$.  But that's impossible if $x(T) \ne 0$, while $(x(T), y(T)) = (0,0)$ implies $(x(t),y(t))=0$ for all $t$ by the uniqueness theorem.